# Parsing matrix using Booleans in Julia

Tags: matrix, vector, boolean, julia

So I am trying to select elements from a matrix using booleans, but I stumble upon this behavior I cannot understand.
Consider the following matrices.

```
id = [1 1 2 2]
x1 = [1 2 3 4 ]
x2 = [5 6 7 8 ]
X = transpose([x1 ; x2 ])
```

Now I want to select all the elements in `X` that correspond to `id==1`. This is one way to do it.

```
X[ [true ,true, false ,false ] , : ]
# 2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
# 1  5
# 2  6
```

However, when I create the boolean using logical conditions, it fails to produce the desired result.

```
select_row = isone.(transpose(id).==1) 
X[ select_row , : ]
# 2×1 Matrix{Int64}:
# 1
# 2
```

Any idea about what is happening? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First let me comment how to solve your issue. Your `select_row` selector must be a vector, so the following will work:

```
julia> select_row = vec(transpose(id).==1)
4-element BitVector:
 1
 1
 0
 0

julia> X[select_row, :]
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  5
 2  6
```

In your case `select_row` is a 4x1 matrix:

```
julia> select_row = isone.(transpose(id).==1)
4×1 BitMatrix:
 1
 1
 0
 0
```

in which case we hit a situation that is not well documented in the Julia Manual how this should be handled (I will discuss this case with core team and comment here is there is an official interpretation for it).

Comment: From the code in Base, it seems the `BitMatrix` ultimately becomes `CartesianIndex{2}[CartesianIndex(1, 1), CartesianIndex(2, 1)]`; and because it's 2-dimensional, it takes up the first two dimensions of indexing, and the `:` becomes an index into the non-existent third dimension (and hence ignored, like the `:`s in `X[2, 3, :, :, :]` for eg.). I'm also interested in how much of this is intended behaviour and how much is just emergent (if any).

Comment: The issue is caused by https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/38193. I opened the discussion there to settle down what should be the correct behavior.

Comment: The trailing `:` being ignored makes sense in the context of the rest of the language, the surprising thing to me was that *incomplete* logical indexing works i.e. the Bool array used for indexing doesn't have to be the same size as the array being indexed into. In fact, when converting to (Cartesian) indices, the original array is just not used, and the true elements' indices are returned wherever they are; effectively it's as if the rest of the Bool array was full of `false` values.

Comment: That's good to know, especially that the manual explicitly states the same length/size requirement - even though the current behaviour is probably exploitable in code golfing in some way :)

Comment: As you highlight - the fact that this behavior does not match the documentation was the reason I have commented in the PR.